# Cannot resolve method/symbol in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

This is first experience with Android Studio and first question I have asked on here so sorry if I ask incorrectly.

I am getting an errors throughout my code such as Cannot resolve symbol 'name' and Cannot resolve method 'show()'.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.i("Activity Lifecycle", "onCreate");

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String name = extras.getString(  "ExtraName");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            text:"This is the extra string that we passed in: " + name,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void openCoinToss(View view){
    //do something in response to button click
    Intent openCoinTossIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CoinTossActivity.class);
    openCoinTossIntent.putExtra(name: "ExtraName", value: "ExtraValue");
    startActivity(openCoinTossIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent openCoinTossIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CoinTossActivity.class);
    openCoinTossIntent.putExtra(name: "ExtraName", value: "ExtraValue");
```

should be:

```
Intent openCoinTossIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CoinTossActivity.class);
    openCoinTossIntent.putExtra( "ExtraName",  "ExtraValue");
```

What version of the JDK are you using? I'm not aware of being able to pass in named arguments in Java.

and

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String name = extras.getString(  "ExtraName");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            text:"This is the extra string that we passed in: " + name,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

should be:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String name = extras.getString(  "ExtraName");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "This is the extra string that we passed in: " + name,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: That's not a java version issue, such a thing doesnt exist in java. Thats rather an issue of typing code off of a screenshot with intellij's naming hints enabled.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried invalidating caches?

```
File > Invalidate Caches > Invalidate and restart
```